# Year and month conversion in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have convert this `1452361874` value into `2016-01-09 17:51:14` by using below code on sql server.

```
CONVERT (nVarchar(32), DATEADD(s, nDateTime, '01/01/1970'), 20)
```

Now,someone help me to find out individual month and year in different column.

Example:

```
January 1970
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a cross apply allows you to use the column alias ("cDateTime") in columns of the select clause.

```
select
     CONVERT(nVarchar(32), ca.cDateTime , 20) as nDateTime
   , DATENAME(MONTH, ca.cDateTime)
   + ' ' + CONVERT(nVarChar,YEAR(ca.cDateTime)) as mnth_yr
from yourtable
cross apply ( 
    select DATEADD(s, nDateTime, '19700101')
  ) ca (cDateTime)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have declared one variable to set value, and tried something like this.

To check output - execute below lines in your SQL,

```
DECLARE @nDateTime AS INT=1452361874  
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(32) ,DATEADD(s ,@nDateTime ,'01/01/1970') ,20)) MonthN,YEAR(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(32) ,DATEADD(s ,@nDateTime ,'01/01/1970') ,20)) YearN
```

As per your query you should write like below,

```
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH,CONVERT(NVARCHAR(32) ,DATEADD(s ,nDateTime ,'01/01/1970') ,20)) MonthName,YEAR(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(32) ,DATEADD(s ,nDateTime ,'01/01/1970') ,20)) YearName
```

Comment: Will you help me to find out the year

Comment: have you checked the output of above query, it showing year also. if you have different query then please let me know with some explanation thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can select them as follows

```
SELECT DATENAME(month,MONTH( DATEADD(s, nDateTime, '01/01/1970'))) as [month],YEAR( DATEADD(s, nDateTime, '01/01/1970')) as [year]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @dateval DATETIME

SET @dateval = CONVERT(NVARCHAR(32), DATEADD(s, 1452361874, '01/01/1970'), 20)

SELECT (CONVERT(VARCHAR(40), datename(month, month(@dateval))) + ' ' + 
convert(VARCHAR(40), YEAR(@dateval))) AS 'Date'
```

Comment: he has mentioned  `to find out individual month and year in different column.`